# is there a way to tell if a record is new after it's been created with find_or_create_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I'm using this code:

```
item = Item.find_or_create_by(:name => title.strip)
if item.changed?
   results.newItemsCount += 1
end
```

I want to get the count of newly created records for logging. I was hoping that the .changed property would be true for items that are newly created but it looks like it isn't. The next part of the code may modify the item even if it isn't new, so I really need to know right here if the item is new.

Is there a way to tell if the record is new or not? Didn't see anything like that [in the docs](http://mongoid.org/docs/documents/dirty.html). You'd think that just setting the title (in the constructor) would  qualify as changed but it seems like that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think its possible to find whether the call was find or create using `changed?` or `persisted?` methods.

Instead you can do this by `find_or_initialize_by`. Here you can check `persisted?` value to determine the item is new or not. if its false then you know that its a new document.

```
item = Item.find_or_initialize_by(:name => title.strip)
unless item.persisted?
   item.save 
   results.newItemsCount += 1
end
```

Other way is you can use `after_create` callback. if its a new item this callback will be triggered. And you can do your operation here.

Hope it helps

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. The docs weren't very clear on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is too late, but it is possible.
You can pass a block like this:

```
item = Item.find_or_create_by(:name => title.strip) do |_i|
  puts "Called only for newly created records"
end
```

Hope it will help somebody.